# I'm trying to create a memory game in assembly 8086. I'm using dosbox so its very hard to debug. I dont understand why my code does not work

Tags: assembly

I have many problems in my code that i do not know how to solve:
1. When i clicked on square i can't click on another one without clicking on it at least 8 times.
2. When the player finishes his first turn he cannot click on another pair of square's.
3. I tried to fix the problem of clicking on an existing square but it did not work.
Thanks you so much if you can help me with this and i apologize for the bad English.

The game works like this: Player one clicks on a square. The findColor proc goes through the coordinates and checks what square was clicked and what color is that square. Next the showColor paint's the cube. Now i compare the inTurn(internal Turn) to 1 - i want to check the number of squares the player clicked on. If the player only clicked on 1 square then i jump to waitMS to paint another one. When the player painted two squares i compare the color of the first square to the second color. I delete the square if they are not the same color with the isSame proc. Finally i check if all 8 pairs have been discoverd([turn]). If all 8 have been discoverd i compare the two scores to check who won. If not all 8 pairs have been discoverd i jump back to prog for another turn.
        Thank you again if you'r willing to help me.
        [Status window if two square's are not the same color and need to be deleted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPaVk.jpg)
        [screen after one click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyNoM.jpg)
        [screen at start of the game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjypH.jpg)

```
        IDEAL 

        MODEL small
        STACK 0f500h
        MAX_BMP_WIDTH = 320
        MAX_BMP_HEIGHT = 200

        SMALL_BMP_HEIGHT = 40
        SMALL_BMP_WIDTH = 40

        DATASEG
        first_s db 'first_screen.bmp', 0
        teco_s db 'teco.bmp', 0
        win_1 db 'win_screen_1.bmp', 0
        win_2 db 'win_screen_2.bmp', 0
        sizeX dw 80d
        sizeY dw 50d
        x1 dw 3d ; temp x
        y1 dw 3d
        x dw 3d
        y dw 3d
        x2 dw ?
        y2 dw ?
        x3 dw ?
        x4 dw ?
        turn dw 0 ; number of pairs found
        Score1 dw 0
        Score2 dw 2
        inTurn db 0
        outTurn dw 0
        tempX dw ?
        tempY dw ?
        board db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        num dw 49
        color db 4
        color2 db 8
        OneBmpLine     db MAX_BMP_WIDTH dup (0)  ; One Color line read              
        buffer
        ScreenLineMax     db MAX_BMP_WIDTH dup (0)  ; One Color line read 
        buffer
        ;BMP File data
        FileHandle    dw ?
        Header         db 54 dup(0)
        Palette     db 400h dup (0)
        SmallPicName db 'zicaron.bmp',0
        BmpFileErrorMsg        db 'Error At Opening Bmp File .', 0dh,
        0ah,'$'
        ErrorFile           db 0
        BB db "BB..",'$'     
        BmpLeft dw ?
        BmpTop dw ?
        two db 2
        BmpColSize dw ?
        BmpRowSize dw ?     
        location db 0
        location2 db 0
        CODESEG
        start:
        mov ax, @data
        mov ds, ax
        mov ax,13h
        int 10h
        mov [BmpLeft],0
        mov [BmpTop],0
        mov [BmpColSize], 320
        mov [BmpRowSize] ,200
        mov dx,offset SmallPicName
        call OpenShowBmp 

        prog:
        mov [inTurn], 0
        inc [outTurn]
        mov ax, 0h
        int 33h
        mov ax, 1h
        int 33h

        waitMS:
        mov ax, 1h
        int 33h
        mov ax, 3h
        int 33h
        cmp bx, 01h ; בדיקה אם כפתור שמאלי של העכבר הוקלק
        jne waitMS
        shr cx, 1  ; X ערך
        sub dx, 1 ; Y ערך
        call findColor ; find the box to draw
        call showColor ; call to paint the box

        ;-----------------------
        cmp [inTurn], 1
        jne check
        mov ah, [location]
        mov [location2], ah
        jmp waitMS

        check:
        call isSame
        cmp [turn], 8
        jge finalWinner
        jmp prog


        finalWinner: 
        push [Score1]
        pop bx
        cmp [Score2], bx
        jg Screen_Win_2
        cmp [Score2], bx
        jl Screen_Win_1
        tie:
        mov dx, offset teco_s
        call OpenShowBmp
        mov ah,00h
        int 16h
        jmp exit
        Screen_Win_1:
        mov dx, offset win_1
        call OpenShowBmp
        mov ah,00h
        int 16h
        jmp exit
        Screen_Win_2:
        mov dx, offset win_2
        call OpenShowBmp
        mov ah,00h
        int 16h
        jmp exit
        exit:
        mov dx, offset BB
        mov ah,9
        ;int 21h
        mov ah,0
        int 16h
        mov ax,2
        int 10h
        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h    
        proc showColor near
        mov ax,2h
        int 33h
        push [x]
        pop [tempX]
        mov cx, 46
        raw:
        push cx
        mov cx, 75     
        doit: 
        push cx   
        ; Print one dot
        mov bh,0h
        mov cx, [x]
        mov dx, [y]
        mov al, [color]
        mov ah,0ch
        int 10h
        inc [x]
        pop cx
        loop doit   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        pop cx
        inc [y]
        push [tempX]
        pop [x]
        loop raw   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
        ret
         endp showColor
        proc timeDelay near
        mov cx, 0Fh
        mov dx, 4240h
        mov ah, 86h
        int 15h

        ret
        endp timeDelay
        proc findColor near
        mov bx, offset board
        cmp cx, 80
        jl firstC
        cmp cx, 160
        jl secondC
        cmp cx, 240
        jl thirdC
        mov [x], 243
        call fourthCP
        jmp ext
        thirdC:
        mov [x], 163
        call thirdCP
         jmp ext
        secondC:
        mov [x], 83
        call secondCP
         jmp ext
       firstC:
       mov [x], 3
       call firstCP

       ext:
        cmp [byte ptr bx + location], 0
       je nxt
       call callWaitMS
       nxt:
        mov [bx + location], 1
       inc [inTurn]
        cmp [inTurn], 1
       jne timeToLeave
       mov ah, [color]
       mov [color2], ah
       push [x]
       pop [x1]
       push [y]
       pop [y1]
       mov ah, [location]
       mov [location2], ah
       jmp plsExt

       timeToLeave:
       push [x]
       pop [x2]
       push [y]
       pop [y2]

       plsExt:
       ret
       endp findColor
       proc callWaitMS near
       jmp waitMS

    ret
    endp callWaitMS
    proc fourthCP near 
    cmp dx, 50
    jl oneL
    cmp dx, 100
    jl twoL
    cmp dx, 150
    jle thirdL
    fourthL:
    mov [location], 15
    mov [y], 154
    mov [color], 5h
    jmp extD
    thirdL:
    mov [location], 14
    mov [y], 104
    mov [color], 3h
    jmp extD
    twoL:
    mov [location], 13
    mov [y], 54
    mov [color], 2h
    jmp extD
    oneL:
    mov [location], 12
    mov[y], 4
    mov [color], 9h
    jmp extD
    extD:
    ret
    endp fourthCP
    proc thirdCP near
    cmp dx, 50
    jl oneLS
    cmp dx, 100
    jl twoLS
    cmp dx, 150
    jle thirdLS
    fourthLS:
    mov [location], 11
    mov [y], 154
    mov [color], 15h
    jmp extT
    thirdLS:
    mov [location], 10
    mov [y], 104
    mov [color], 6h
    jmp extT
    twoLS:
    mov [location], 9
    mov [y], 54
    mov [color], 14h
    jmp extT
    oneLS:
    mov [location], 8
    mov [y], 4
    mov [color], 3h
    jmp extT
    extT:
    ret
    endp thirdCP
    proc secondCP near

    cmp dx, 50
    jl oneLT
    cmp dx, 100
    jl twoLT
    cmp dx, 150
    jl thirdLT
    fourthLT:
    mov [location], 7
    mov [y], 154
    mov [color], 2h
    jmp extS
    thirdLT:
    mov [location], 6
    mov [y], 104
    mov [color], 9h
    jmp extS
    twoLT:
    mov [location], 5
    mov [y], 54
    mov [color], 14h
    jmp extS
    oneLT:
    mov [location], 4
    mov [y], 4
    mov [color], 5h
    jmp extS
    extS:
    ret
    endp secondCP
    proc firstCP near

    cmp dx, 50
    jl oneLA
    cmp dx, 100
    jl twoLA
    cmp dx, 150
    jl thirdLA
    fourthLA:
    mov [location], 3
    mov [y], 154
    mov [color], 12h
    jmp extF
    thirdLA:
    mov [location], 2
    mov [y], 104
    mov [color], 15h
    jmp extF
    twoLA:
    mov [location], 1
    mov [y], 54
    mov [color], 12h
    jmp extF
    oneLA:
    mov [location], 0
    mov [y], 4
    mov [color], 6h
    jmp extF
    extF:
    ret
    endp firstCP
    proc isSame near
    mov bx, offset board    
    mov ah, [color2]
    cmp [color], ah
    jne calc
    inc [turn]
    push [outTurn]
    pop ax
    div [two]
    cmp ah , 0
    jne playerOne
    cmp ah, 1
    jne playerTwo
    playerOne:
    inc [turn]
    inc [Score1]
    jmp prog
    playerTwo:
    inc [turn]
    inc [Score2]
    jmp prog
    calc:
    call timeDelay
    call timeDelay
    mov  [bx + location], 0
    mov [bx + location2], 0
    mov [color], 0
    push [x2]
    pop [x]
    push [y2]
    pop [y]
    push [x2]
    pop [tempX]
    call showColor
    push [x1]
    pop [x]
    push [y1]
    pop [y]
    push [x1]
    pop [tempX]
    call showColor
    jmp prog
    ret
    endp isSame

    ;========================
    ;==========================
    ;===== Procedures  Area ===
    ;==========================
    ;==========================
    ; input :
    ;    1.BmpLeft offset from left (where to start draw the picture) 
    ;    2. BmpTop offset from top
    ;    3. BmpColSize picture width , 
    ;    4. BmpRowSize bmp height 
    ;    5. dx offset to file name with zero at the end 
    proc OpenShowBmp near
        push cx
        push bx
        call OpenBmpFile
        cmp [ErrorFile],1
        je @@ExitProc
        call ReadBmpHeader
        ; from  here assume bx is global param with file handle. 
        call ReadBmpPalette
        call CopyBmpPalette
        call ShowBMP 
        call CloseBmpFile
      @@ExitProc:
        pop bx
        pop cx
        ret
      endp OpenShowBmp    
    ; input dx filename to open
    proc OpenBmpFile    near                         
        mov ah, 3Dh
        xor al, al
        int 21h
        jc @@ErrorAtOpen
        mov [FileHandle], ax
        jmp @@ExitProc    
       @@ErrorAtOpen:
        mov [ErrorFile],1
       @@ExitProc:    
        ret
       endp OpenBmpFile

       proc CloseBmpFile near
        mov ah,3Eh
        mov bx, [FileHandle]
        int 21h
        ret
       endp CloseBmpFile




    ; Read 54 bytes the Header
    proc ReadBmpHeader    near                    
        push cx
        push dx

        mov ah,3fh
        mov bx, [FileHandle]
        mov cx,54
        mov dx,offset Header
        int 21h

        pop dx
        pop cx
        ret
    endp ReadBmpHeader



    proc ReadBmpPalette near 
                             ; 4 bytes for each color BGR + null)            
        push cx
        push dx

        mov ah,3fh
        mov cx,400h
        mov dx,offset Palette
        int 21h

        pop dx
        pop cx

        ret
       endp ReadBmpPalette


    ; Will move out to screen memory the colors
    ; video ports are 3C8h for number of first color
    ; and 3C9h for all rest
     proc CopyBmpPalette        near                    

        push cx
        push dx

        mov si,offset Palette
        mov cx,256
        mov dx,3C8h
        mov al,0  ; black first                            
        out dx,al ;3C8h
        inc dx      ;3C9h
    CopyNextColor:
        mov al,[si+2]         ; Red                
        shr al,2                         
        out dx,al                         
        mov al,[si+1]         ; Green.                
        shr al,2            
        out dx,al                             
        mov al,[si]         ; Blue.                
        shr al,2            
        out dx,al                             
        add si,4                           

        loop CopyNextColor

        pop dx
        pop cx

        ret
        endp CopyBmpPalette













    proc ShowBMP 
    ; BMP graphics are saved upside-down.
    ; Read the graphic line by line (BmpRowSize lines in VGA format),
    ; displaying the lines from bottom to top.
        push cx

        mov ax, 0A000h
        mov es, ax

        mov cx,[BmpRowSize]

        mov ax,[BmpColSize] ;
        xor dx,dx
        mov si,4
        div si
        mov bp,dx

        mov dx,[BmpLeft]

      @@NextLine:
        push cx
        push dx

        mov di,cx  ; Current Row at the small bmp (each time -1)
        add di,[BmpTop] ; add the Y on entire screen



        mov cx,di
        shl cx,6
        shl di,8
        add di,cx
        add di,dx

        ; small Read one line
        mov ah,3fh
        mov cx,[BmpColSize]  
        add cx,bp  ; extra  bytes to each row must be divided by 4
        mov dx,offset ScreenLineMax
        int 21h
        ; Copy one line into video memory
        cld ; Clear direction flag, for movsb
        mov cx,[BmpColSize]  
        mov si,offset ScreenLineMax
        rep movsb ; Copy line to the screen

        pop dx
        pop cx

        loop @@NextLine

        pop cx
        ret
       endp ShowBMP 



    proc  SetGraphic
        mov ax,13h   ; 320 X 200 
        int 10h
        ret
     endp     SetGraphic








    END start
```

Comment: See if you can find and download a copy of Masm 6.11 along with the rest of the 16 bit toolset, or at least codeview (source level debugger).

Comment: I never had a problem debugging DOS applications in DosBox with Borland Turbo Debugger.
https://euroassembler.eu/eadoc/links.htm#TASM